# Does each sequence $\Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ satisfy a linear return relationship?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory

Suppose $a(n)$ is a sequence $a:\Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ and $\forall i \in \Bbb N,\, s_i(n):\Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ is $s_{i+1}(n)=a(a(a(...(n))))$ such that $i$ times combine was done.

Question: whether $k,m_1,m_2,...,m_k \in \Bbb Z$ exist such that $m_1s_1+m_2s_2+...+m_ks_k=0$.

I thank you in advance.

Comment: Couldn't you just always choose $k = 2$, $m_1 = s_2$, and $m_2 = -s_1$?

Comment: Or choose any $k$, let $m_2 = \cdots = m_k = -s_1$, and let $m_1 = s_2+\cdots+s_k$?

Comment: Michael lee, $s_i$ is mapping and $m_i$ is integer, don't?

Comment: I'm sorry, I misinterpreted. In that case, you're looking for a sequence $a$ such that the $s_i$ are all linearly independent?

Comment: Michael Lee, I like your comments, somehow we're similar, your comments are **chap andar gheichi** just like me! (chap andar gheichi is Persian and I don't know its translation.)

Comment: "Left-handed scissors," perhaps?

Comment: No, it is **Left form scissors** of course not exactly!

Comment: **Left form scissors** is a scissors with bent blade for cutting iron thin sheet but in a circle path instead direct, and I feel it points to bent way instead direct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $a(n)=n^2$. We have $s_i(n)=n^{2^i}$ so the $s_i$ are linearly independent. Indeed, suppose we have a relation

$$m_1s_1+\cdots+m_ks_k=0.
$$

Without loss of generality, we can assume $m_k \neq 0$. Dividing by $s_k$ yields for every $n$

$$m_1n^{2-2^k}+m_2n^{4-2^k}+\cdots+m_k=0,
$$

so taking the limit when $n\to +\infty$ gives us a contradiction.

Comment: Q: Does there exist  an injective $a:N\to N$  such that there exist  non-zero $k,\;m_1,...,m_k$  such that $\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} m_ja^j(n)=0$ for all $n$?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Yes. Let $a(n) = n$. Then $s_i(n) = n$ for all $i$.

Comment: @MichaelLee. ..Obvious, now that you've shown me.